# sum of 4 fields should be 100 and those fields are not always required to be filled

Tags: laravel, validation

```
 'boulders_per' => 'numeric',
            'fine_soil_per' => 'numeric',
            Rule::sometimes(function () {
                $sum = $this->input('boulders_per', 0) + $this->input('fine_soil_per', 0);
                return $sum !== 100;
            }),
```

used requiredif bt these fileds are not always required to be filled and using sometimes its shows error
"message": "Method Illuminate\Validation\Rule::sometimes does not exist.",

Answer (score 0):

You might try to implement this on top of your controller(or wherever you use that function):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Method : 1**

You must use [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules) for single attribute validations.

There is a provision in [After Validation Hooks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#after-validation-hook) where such kind of complex validation can be written

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if ($this->get('your_field_1') + $this->get('your_field_2') + $this->get('your_field_3') + $this->get('your_field_4') != 100) {
            $validator->errors()->add(null, 'The sum of field1, field2 and field3 and field4 must be 100');
        }
    });
}
```

**Method : 2**

Your can convert the value from an array to a collection and use the [sum collect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sum) method

```
public function passes($attribute, $value) {
    $values = collect($value);    
    return $values->sum('percentage') <= 100;
}
```